# Counting Ordered Pairs

Tags: equivalence-relations

Let $A$ be a finite set with $n \geq 4$ elements and let $\rho$ be an equivalence relation on $A$. Suppose that there are exactly $4$ equivalence classes, $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$, $C_4$. Moreover we know that $|C_1| = |C_2| = 1$. Let $a\in A$ be a fixed element that we know is in $C_3$.
What is the maximum number of ordered pairs of $(x, y) \in \rho$ in which a can occur (meaning $a = x$ or $a = y$ or $a = x = y$)?

Comment: This is what I currently have: In order to maximize the number of pairs that contain $a$, $|C_4|$ must also be equal to 1. If $n$ = 4, there is only one possible pair that contains $a$, which is ($a, a$). When $n$ = 5, you can add the fifth element, say $b$, to [$a$]. This would add the pairs ($a,b$) and ($b,a$). Therefore, each time you are adding two more possible pairs containing $a$. The answer ends up being $2n - 7$.

Comment: +1 for showing your thoughts on the question.  It makes it much easier to give a(n |I hope) useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You are correct that to maximize the number of pairs you should have $|C_4|=1$, which gives $|C_3|=n-3$  But when you add the third element to $C_3$ you add more than two ordered pairs.  $c$ can be paired with each of $a$ and $b$ in either order, so you add four pairs.  Can you determine what happens for larger $n$?

Comment: I thought $a$ had to be in the pair. Therefore, it only adds two more pairs each time an element is added to $C_3$.